# why are the individual faces are acting reflective?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am really new to Blender this was my attempt to model a Katana sword but the shading looks all weird and I am not sure why.

If anyone can point out why the individual faces are acting reflective instead of the whole sword it would be helpful.

Just as a side question when modelling objects like blades, guns and or people would be best to use individual objects as parts like for example here the sword is all one cube object should i use 1 cube for the blade another for the handle?

EDIT : I have added a 2nd image to show the mesh for this object, Maybe it is all wrong.[image]

MAny Thanks! [image: BlenderShot]

Omg!! Many thanks for the suggestion about smooth shade that was exactly what i wanted!!

Comment: "100% 1st Blender Object" as a title does not at all reflect your question. The title should summarize your question and help people browsing the titles instantly understand your issue. It pays off to give your questions descriptive titles as they get good answers faster.

Comment: what do you mean by "why the individual faces are acting reflective instead of the whole sword", have you given the same material to both the blade and the handle? I guess not. Also I'm not sure what your Layer Weight is here for as your ColorRamp colors seem to be white and white?

Comment: About your last question, most of the time you make one single object for a real object, so one object for your sword, but it's logical to use several meshes within this object if this object is made of different parts, like for example the blade and the handle. That said, for 3D printing, you'll have to make one object with one unique mesh.

Comment: So sorry yes I should have given it a better description..

I was having trouble trying to get a metallic shader to work so I ended up looking for some premade on Blendermada which is where i got this. 

I have a different material for the handle and a different material for the blade but if you look at the blade you can see each individual face is reflecting instead of the whole blade being as one.  To better explain you can see every edge of every face down the blade which is not how a blade looks in real life :)

Im not 3d printing this xD.

Comment: Instead of adding comments, **please use the [edit] link** at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). Ask only one question per post and please take a minute to take the [tour] to understatnd how to make better use of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shade Smooth option, found under Object > Shade Smooth. This will average the face normals so that the object looks smooth.